# Probability from Chi-Squared distribution

Tags: probability, arithmetic

If I have a random variable called $A$ and $A \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, how can I get the value of $X$ if $P(X<5A^2<6.52)=0.5310$. It seems that the answer is $2.4109$, but I don't know how to reach that value.

Thanks!

Comment: Your equation literally seems to state "$\Pr(X\lt 5A^2\lt 6.52)=0.5310.$"  Is this correct?  It shouldn't be, because then the answer wouldn't be $2.4109.$

Comment: Hi @whuber ! Yes, it is; I have another example: Pr(X<79B^2<101)=0.7834, and the suggested answer is X=66.9239. I think something is wrong, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It could be a notational issue.  Is there any way you could post a photo of the problem statement?

Comment: whuber is correct, the answer to the question posted here is not 2.4109 but considerably smaller. (It takes only a single short line in R to get the answer ~ 33 characters); please make certain we have the correct details.

Comment: Because $A^2 \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=1),$ your answer would require R code `diff(pchisq(c(2.4109/5, 6.52/5), 1))`
` to return $0.5310,$ but it actually does return $0.2339527.$ So something is wrong.
 .

Answer (score 0):

Although $A^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$, but $5A^2$ is not, since it can't be expressed as sum of i.i.d. standard normal r.v.s.

$P(5A^2<6.52)=P(A^2<\dfrac{6.52}{5})$ which could be found with `pchisq(1, 6.52/5)` in `R`, e.g.

Also, by change of variable (Jacobian), we can find the the pdf of the r.v. $Y=5A^2$.

$f_Y(y)=f_A(a)\left|\dfrac{da}{ay}\right|=\dfrac{e^{-a^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.\dfrac{1}{10a}=\dfrac{e^{-y/10}}{\sqrt{2\pi}.2\sqrt{5y}}$

Now, $F_Y(6.52) = P(Y\leq 6.52) = \int_{0}^{6.52}f_Y(y)dy=\int_{0}^{6.52}\dfrac{e^{-y/10}}{\sqrt{2\pi}.2\sqrt{5y}}dy$, since $Y \geq 0$

With numerical integration, e.g., with `R`, we can compute the probability.

```
integrate(function(y) exp(-y/10)/sqrt(y), 0, 6.52)$value / (2*sqrt(5)*sqrt(2*pi))
```

Comment: Umm... $5A^2$ divided by $5$ *does* have a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution, so no numerical integration is needed.  There is still an outstanding question concerning what the post is really trying to ask.

Comment: Yeah.. could have used `pchisq(1, 6.52/5)`

Comment: That helps, thank you.  But how do you interpret the question?  It seems to be asking for an unknown threshold $X:$ what value do you obtain for it, and how?